# bloquear pagina de 'autor' do wordpress

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Estou tentando fazer um bloqueio via htaccess quando alguém tenta acessar a pagina de 'autor' do wordpress ( http://meusite.com.br/?author=1 )... achei que essa solução apresentada aqui no forum daria certo, mas não deu... alguém tem alguma solução via htaccess pra isso?

A solução que eu achei aqui no forum foi:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site_exemplo.com.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(noticias/como-bloquear-acesso-a-pagina) - [L,F]
```

Comment: Olá, uma solução seria redirecionar para outra pagina, ou para a pagina inicial.

Comment: é exatamente isso que o meu htacces faz, manda para a pagina principal quando encontra erro tipo 404, sendo assim, eu quero que a pagina de autor dê como erro 404

Comment: não seria mais simples ocultar a pagina de author se você não quer que ela seja exibida?

Comment: na verdade nao sei como fazer para ocultar (se puder indicar algum link sobre isso aqui do forum), mas acredito que se tivesse alguma forma via htaccess, poderia ser usada para outros casos similares, que porventura nao possam ser 'ocultadas'...

Comment: da um alhada nessa (material)[https://br.support.wordpress.com/paginas/visibilidade-da-pagina/] acho que pode te ajudar, tem plugins que fazem isso

Comment: ah sim... isso eu ja conheco, mas para esta pagina de 'author' nao tem como usar essa funcao...

Comment: tentei usar isso mas dá erro de sintaxe, alguem pode tentar para ver se funciona?
https://wordpress.2bearstudio...able-wordpress-author-pages/

contudo, prefiro mesmo via htaccess

Comment: eu tentei isso no htaccess
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (author=\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F] 

deu certo mas cai na pagina de teste do apache...eu queria mesmo que interpretasse como algo do tipo 'erro 404 '

Comment: consegui pessoal!
a solucao que usei foi essa mesmo que indiquei no inicio... 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site_exemplo.com.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(noticias/como-bloquear-acesso-a-pagina) - [L,F]

só faltava ajustar o caminho final...

ps.: nao sei como fechar um topico, mas este ja pode ser fechado

Comment: ficou certinho como eu esperava
http://ineclub.com.br/?author=1

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso te ajuda, é feito direto no functions.php

```
// Disalbe access to author page
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_disable_author_page');

function my_custom_disable_author_page() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_author() ) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        // Redirect to homepage
        // wp_redirect(get_option('home'));
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_author_pages_page' );
```

A mágica acontece na utilização da função is_author(), se quiser ver a lista de todas funções para cada página acesse: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona isso ao arquivo .htaccess, ele irá redirecionar todas as solicitações de autor procurando por um número (ID de Autor) para a página inicial:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?author=([0-9]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```